# Add Limit Line to WPF Column Series

Tags: wpf, charts, line

I am using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting to create a Column Series. This works pretty well. But now i have to add a "Limit Line", which is a simple horizontal line at a defined value. How do I manage this?

Comment: Didnt get this... `But now i have to add a "Limit Line", which is a simple horizontal line at a defined value. `

Comment: The Line is there to visualize the Limit which the bars should reach. It has no influence on the Chart Data itself. For Example: My Goal is to sell 100 $ or more a day, there should be a line at the 100 $ Mark in the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it, by using a Scatter Series and a stretched Line:

```
<DVC:ScatterSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" >
                <DVC:ScatterSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DVC:LegendItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Style>
                    </DVC:ScatterSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                        <DVC:ScatterSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DVC:ScatterDataPoint">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="4000" />
                                 <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:ScatterDataPoint">
                                    <Grid x:Name="Root">
                                        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DVC:ScatterSeries.DataPointStyle>
            </DVC:ScatterSeries>
```